# PHP - limit the file size but somehow got Warning: POST Content-Length exceeds the limit

Tags: php, html

I wanted to test out the file upload code. This is an upload file code and it has the option whether the user has the file to upload or just submit it blankly. I added the error message to limit the file extension. It works.

Then, I added an error message to notify the user about the limit file size. But somehow got the `Warning: POST Content-Length of 681075903 bytes exceeds the limit of 8388608 bytes in Unknown on line 0`

instead of the error message of "Sorry, your file is too large. Only 3MB allowed"  from the php code.

```
<html><head></head>
<body>

<form method="post" action="" enctype="multipart/form-data">

    Upload File:
    <input type="file" name="upload" /><br> 
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit"/>
</form>
</body>
</html>

<?php
include("config.php");
if(isset($_POST['submit'])  ){

//user has the option whether to upload the file or not
if ($_FILES['upload']['size'] != 0 ){

$filename = $con->real_escape_string($_FILES['upload']['name']);
$filedata= $con->real_escape_string(file_get_contents($_FILES['upload']['tmp_name']));
$filetype = $con->real_escape_string($_FILES['upload']['type']);
$filesize = intval($_FILES['upload']['size']);

$allowed =  array('zip','rar', 'pdf', 'doc', 'docx');
$ext = pathinfo($filename, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

if(in_array($ext, $allowed)){           

            if($filesize > 3000000) {
                $query = "INSERT INTO contracts(`filename`,`filedata`, `filetype`,`filesize`) VALUES ('$filename','$filedata','$filetype','$filesize')" ;

                if ($con->query($query) == TRUE) {
                echo "<br><br> New record created successfully";
                } else {
                echo "Error:<br>" . $con->error;
                }

                }
            else{
                echo "Sorry, your file is too large. Only 3MB allowed";
            }
        }
        else{
            echo "Sorry, only zip, rar, pdf, doc & docs files are allowed.";        
        }

//if user has no file to upload then proceed to this else statement
} else {

$filename = $con->real_escape_string($_FILES['upload']['name']);
$filetype = $con->real_escape_string($_FILES['upload']['type']);
$filesize = intval($_FILES['upload']['size']);

$query = "INSERT INTO contracts(`filename`, `filetype`,`filesize`) VALUES ('$filename','$filetype','$filesize')" ;

if ($con->query($query) == TRUE) {
echo "<br><br> New record created successfully";
} else {
echo "Error:<br>" . $con->error;
}

}
$con->close(); 
}   

?>
```

I don't get it. What did I do wrong in this code?

I think it is the `if ($_FILES['upload']['size'] != 0 ){` part that gave the problem but I still want my user to have it optional to upload.

Comment: You can creat a php.ini with max uploud i think that php configuration not allow you to send more data.

php.ini

  ` upload_max_filesize = 'your size'
    post_max_size = 'your size'`

Comment: Make sure the PHP setting `post_max_size` is at least the same as your max upload size.

Comment: As an aside, `if($filesize > 3000000) {` should probably be `< 3000000` - at the moment you're only allowing files that are larger than ~3MB and outputting the "too large" error when they're under that size.

Comment: @CD001 nope. still the same warning it gave me.

Comment: Well yeah, you're trying to upload a 681MB file according to the comments on the answer below. I was just pointing out an error in your code logic. Here's another one - file extensions don't really mean anything. Rename a PDF from `.pdf` to `.bob` and you can still open it with Acrobat Reader.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its not a problem with your code. The http request isnt going through php because of the post max size setting.

Find this line in your php.ini of the server and change it:

```
; http://php.net/post-max-size
post_max_size = [max uploadsize like '32M' or '1G']
```

Comment: It gives me the warning. `Warning: POST Content-Length of 681075903 bytes exceeds the limit of 33554432 bytes in Unknown on line 0`. Still the same problem.

Comment: PHP warning talks about a size of 681 075 903 bytes (681 Mb). In order to allow this file, you have to put a greater value thant that. Try with 1G

Comment: @ Pierre-Olivier Vares It works but it didn't give error message "Sorry, your file is too large. Only 3MB allowed" instead it successfully uploaded to the database. That's not what I want to expected.

Comment: @Hazirah_Halim that's because you're using `>` rather than `<` ... **that** is the logical error I was pointing out.

Comment: @CD001 sorry, I forgot to tell you that I already did follow what you have said. I should have explain the problem briefly instead of just saying 'nope' that would lead to misunderstanding. I already using `<` and it still gave me the same warning post error.

Comment: I think it is the if ($_FILES['upload']['size'] != 0 ){ part that gave the problem but I still want my user to have it optional to upload.

Comment: You should either modify your question, or post a new one. Since 1) It's not the same problem anymore, and 2) the code in your question still show "if filesize > 300000".

It'll helps anybody (you too) have a clear view view of what you're expecting now.

(Don't remove the initial error, but rather keep it - maybe striked through with an explanation of "setting post_max_size removed this error", it will help other people having similar problem to have the full explanation.)

Comment: And reformat your code, please. Incoherent indentation makes it difficult to read.

Answer (score 0):

Can you post the form HTML code ?

The problem is, php has a directive (post_max_size) that limits the size of what he allows in POST - before any execution of your script. So, if this limit is reached, the warning is emitted before your script is called, and $_POST is not filled in.

It would deserves additional testing, but be sure :

- to include MAX_FILE_SIZE hidden field in your form (see http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.post-method.php).
- to set post_max_size to something largely greater to what you want to accept
- to set upload_max_filesize to (at first sight) the value you want.

In addition, it would also be intersting to try setting the maxlength attributes on the input, as this is is stated in the RFC-1867.

> If the INPUT tag includes the attribute MAXLENGTH, the user agent should consider its value to represent the maximum Content-Length which the server will accept for transferred files.
>
> In this way, servers can hint to the client how much space they have available for a file upload, before that upload takes place.  It is important to note, however, that this is only a hint, and the actual requirements of the server may change between form creation and file submission.

This would allow to forbid the upload directly in the browser that respect the RFC.

Comment: Edited. Please check my question again.

Comment: In summary :
* Include a maxlength attribute (for browsers respcting the RFC)
* include MAX_FILE_SIZE hidden input
* set post_max_size to something greater; however, by definition you won't be able to catch file greater than that (since PHP would reject it before running your script).
* set max_upload_size to the max you want. PHP will generate for you an 'error' key in the $_FILES array